# Flutter App stuck at splash screen not moving to login page or homepage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await, firebase-authentication

I tried to add splash screen to add splash screen to my app but it gets stuck at splash screen itsalf and  does not move to next screens
I have added the code here:-

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserInfo();
  }

  Future getUserInfo() async {
    await getUser();
    setState(() {});
    print(uid);
    navigateUser();
  }
  navigateUser()
  {
    if(uid!=null && authSignedIn != false)
      {
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 2),
            ()=>Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/toprofilepage")

    );
      }
    else{
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2),
          ()=>Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/tologinpage")
      );
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Login',
      initial route:'/',
      routes: {
        '/toprofilepage':(context)=>FirstScreen(),
        '/tologinpage':(context)=>LoginPage(),
      },
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Saraswat",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this following message in console also:-

> E/flutter ( 5947): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Code for sign in:-

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

bool authSignedIn;
String uid;
String name;
String imageUrl;
Future getUser() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool authSignedIn = prefs.getBool('auth') ?? false;

  final User user = _auth.currentUser;

  if (authSignedIn == true) {
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      name = user.displayName;

      imageUrl = user.photoURL;
    }
  }
}

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = userCredential.user;

  if (user != null) {
    // Checking if email and name is null
    assert(user.uid != null);

    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(user.photoURL != null);

    uid = user.uid;
    name = user.displayName;

    imageUrl = user.photoURL;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('auth', true);

    return 'Google sign in successful, User UID: ${user.uid}';
  }

  return null;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _auth.signOut();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('auth', false);

  uid = null;
  name = null;

  imageUrl = null;

  print("User signed out of Google account");
}
```

I tried a lot of things but did not get any solution pls help!.Should I place the navigator function anywhere else or is there some other error pls help!.

Comment: try to remove the  initial route

Comment: @TabarekGhassan Then how will the splash screen work?

Comment: add it in the home inside MaterialApp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing the flow conditions in initialRoute only

Since the firebase has updated the way we check the user is logged in or not. Its not a async task so you can use directly in the MyApp class.

```
initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
          ? HomeScreen.route_name
          : AuthScreen.route_name
```

Or you can use the listener for auth change

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser) {
    // do whatever you want based on the firebaseUser state
  });
```

so when the auth is changed it will re-direct it to the page you want to, like this

```
home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (streamContext, userSnapshot) {
          if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return SplashScreen();
          if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
            return HomeScreen();
          }
          return AuthScreen();
        },
      ),
```